# How to load a particular page shared as link in react native app webview (deep linking)

Tags: react-native, react-native-webview

I have a react native app which uses react-native-webview to load my site. I have setup deep linking for both android. Now when we try to open a link shared via slack or any other app for example: https://example.com/some-link, it opens my app but does not navigate to the particular shared url or the correct page.

I have tried OnNavigationStateChange, OnLoadStart, onShouldStartLoadWithRequest but not able to get the url that has to be opened.

Any suggestion or help is much appreciated

Thanks you

Comment: Use `Linking.getInitialURL` to get the data sent from other app and you can then use that data for your purpose. [Documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/linking#getinitialurl)

Comment: @RohitAggarwal still getting null when I try to implement.

Comment: Is your app opened when you're redirecting to your app? You can add `Linking.addEventListener('url', yourFunc)` on your Root component.

Comment: @RohitAggarwal that works, thanks for your help. Another mistake I was doing was I was testing it in a debug mode as documentation says we need to create build and then test it or by disabling debug mode https://reactnative.dev/docs/linking#getinitialurl